# search using multiple criteria vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
 Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyConn.Open()
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM [maint]"
    dt.Clear()
    If R1.Checked Then sql = sql & " where datevisite like '%" & dateintervention.Text & "%'  "
    If R2.Checked Then sql = sql & "  [centr] ='" & Me.centra.Text & "'"
    If R3.Checked Then sql = sql & "and  [Priorité] ='" & Me.Priorite.Text & "'"
    If R4.Checked Then sql = sql & "and [Etat_intervention] ='" & Me.etat.Text & "'"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, MyConn)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    DGV.DataSource = dt
    DGV.Refresh()
    MyConn.Close()
  End Sub
```

problem =Syntax error in FROM clause. I want to search using multiple critera using checkbox R1 R2 R3 R4 and the resultat in my datagridview

Comment: possible duplicate of [search using multiple criteria vb.net with a database Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038992/search-using-multiple-criteria-vb-net-with-a-database-access) ...for R2 there is an `AND` missing...and use SQL parameters always

Comment: You might want to try building the where clause in a separate variable then concatenate that with the select statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a space between your search statements:

```
If R1.Checked Then sql = sql & " where datevisite like '%" & dateintervention.Text & "%'  "
If R2.Checked Then sql = sql & "  [centr] ='" & Me.centra.Text & "' "
If R3.Checked Then sql = sql & " and  [Priorité] ='" & Me.Priorite.Text & "' "
If R4.Checked Then sql = sql & " and [Etat_intervention] ='" & Me.etat.Text & "' "
```

Your SQL reads like this: where datevisite like '%%'and  [Priorité] =''and

Better Solution:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyConn.Open()
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM [maint] where 1=1 "
    dt.Clear()
    If R1.Checked Then sql = sql & " and datevisite like '%" & dateintervention.Text & "%'  "
    If R2.Checked Then sql = sql & " and  [centr] ='" & Me.centra.Text & "'"
    If R3.Checked Then sql = sql & " and  [Priorité] ='" & Me.Priorite.Text & "'"
    If R4.Checked Then sql = sql & " and [Etat_intervention] ='" & Me.etat.Text & "'"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, MyConn)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    DGV.DataSource = dt
    DGV.Refresh()
    MyConn.Close()   
End Sub
```

With Parameters:

```
    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM [maint] where 1=1 "

    Try

        MyConn.Open()
        dt.Clear()

        If R1.Checked Then
            sql = sql & " and datevisite like ''  "
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("datevisite", "%" & dateintervention.Text & "%")
        End If

        If R2.Checked Then
            sql = sql & " and  [centr] =  ? "
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("centr", Me.centra.Text)
        End If

        If R3.Checked Then
            sql = sql & " and  [Priorité] = ? "
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Priorité", Me.Priorite.Text)
        End If

        If R4.Checked Then
            sql = sql & " and [Etat_intervention] = ? "
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Etat_intervention", Me.etat.Text)
        End If

        command.Connection = MyConn
        command.CommandText = sql

        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(dt)

        DGV.DataSource = dt
        DGV.Refresh()

    Catch exp As Exception
        Throw exp
    Finally
        If MyConn IsNot Nothing Then MyConn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: not to mention using parameters is highly and strongly recommended. also helps to avoid little issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

If R1.Checked is false and R2.Checked is true, then you have no WHERE keyword ... your not building the dynamic SQL statement properly.

Also this is highly susceptible to SQL Injection